# Swift: "Expected expression after operator" error in NSManaged while trying to push a record to entity

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode8, nsmanagedobject

I've an entity where there are 4 string attributes. I'm trying to push a record into the entity but I'm facing 'Expected Expression after operator' error in record line.

```
   guard
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    //2
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Details", in: managedContext) !
    //3
    let record = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
let entity = ....... "Details", in: managedContext)!   /// ! should be beside the line
```